# Overriding a breeze entity value getter setter seems to break change tracking

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

I am using breeze to communicate with Web.API 2.1
In my backend I save some values as a list of strings (instead of saving one-to-many relations). In the front end I want to break these values, edit them, put them back together and persist them to the DB.

emailsString is the actual property that is persisted to the DB and exists in the model.
fullName acts as an "interface" to reading and modifying the first and last name properties.

I have the following:

```
function registerUserProfile(metadataStore) {
            metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('UserProfile', profile, profileInitializer);


        function profile() {
            this.fullName = '';
            this.emails = [];

        }

        function profileInitializer(newItem) {
            if (!newItem.emailsString || newItem.emailsString.length === 0) newItem.emails = [{ email: '' }];
        }

        Object.defineProperty(profile.prototype, 'fullName', {
            get: function() {
                var fn = this.firstName;
                var ln = this.lastName;
                return ln ? fn + ' ' + ln : fn;

            },
            set: function (value) {
                var parts = value.split(' ');
                this.firstName = parts.shift();
                this.lastName = parts.shift() || '';
            }
        });

        Object.defineProperty(profile.prototype, 'emailsString', {
            get: function () {
                return objectToStringArray(this.emails, 'email');
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this.emails = stringToObjArray(value, 'email');
            }
        });


        function objectToStringArray(objectArray, objectValueKey) {
            var retVal = '';
            angular.forEach(objectArray, function (obj) {
                retVal += obj[objectValueKey] + ';';
            });
            if (retVal.length > 0)
                retVal = retVal.substring(0, retVal.length - 1); //remove last ;
            return retVal;
        }

        function stringToObjArray(stringArray, objectValueKey) {
            var objArray = [];
            angular.forEach(stringArray.split(';'), function (str) {
                var item = {};
                item[objectValueKey] = str;
                objArray.push(item);
            });
            return objArray;
        }
```

If I modify the emailString value and call saveChanges on breeze nothing happens. If I modify the fullName property ALL changes are detected and saveChanges sends the correct JSON object for saving (including emailString value).

From what I understand, overriding the emailString property I somehow break the change tracking for this property. fullName is not a mapped property and thus is not overriding anything so it works. Am I going the correct way? If so is there a way to notify breeze that the overriden property has changed?

Answer (score 0):

In general, Breeze takes over each property on an object and insures that internally it is informed about any changes to each property. How this is done is different depending on whether you are using Angular, Knockout or Backbone ( or a custom modelLibrary adapter).

But if you plan on modifying the property yourself to do something similar you need to insure that breeze is still getting notified.

Based on your posted code I'm assuming that you are using Angular.  In that case you first need to determine whether your code is getting executed before or after Breeze's code.

My guess is that if you make your changes early enough then Breeze will be able to wrap them successfully.  However, if your changes occur after Breeze's then you need to insure that Breeze's code is invoked as well. Debugging into the source for this is probably your best bet. And the Breeze Angular adapter is a good source as a example of how to wrap a property that might already be wrapped with another *defineProperty*.